# UIDeviceFamily only for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to submit a application which can only run on iphone device. But when i select the UIDeviceFamily as iPhone its giving me iPhone/ iPod in the description. I am using camera in the application ? Ny suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your app's plist, add an array for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and add the string "still-camera" to that array.